# Not able to download zip file from server using Angular

Tags: angular, flask, zip, sftp, php-ziparchive

I am trying to download a zip file from a server using Angular.

Flask code:

```
return send_file('<path>/filename.zip', attachment_filename='filename.zip', as_attachment=True)
```

Angular Code:

```
saveFile() {
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/zip');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Token ' + <some token>);
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
this.http.post('http://<server>:<port>/api/<urlpath>', {'somefield': 'somedata'}, { headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer})
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response));
}

str2bytes(str: string) {
const bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
for (let i= 0; i< str.length; i++) {
  bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
}
return bytes;
}

private saveToFileSystem(response: any) {
const filename = 'file.zip';
const blob = new Blob([this.str2bytes(response._body)], {type: 'application/zip'});
saveAs(blob, filename);
}
```

With this, I am able to download the file but not able to unzip it. The error is

> The archive is either in unknown format or damaged

I see that there are differences in `HTTP` implementations in Angular 5 and Angular 6. Correct me if I am wrong. If yes, I am looking for a solution using Angular 6. Also, I was thinking if there is a way to return a connection (say SFTP or anything like that) instead of the file itself and stream the file over the connection and then close the connection. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I found my mistake. I have to use `reponse._body` as it is and not convert it to bytes. So, 
`const blob = new Blob([this.str2bytes(response._body)], {type: 'application/zip'});` should be `const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'application/zip' });`. No use of the `str2bytes` function here. But this is working fine only in Angular 5 but not in Angular 6. I am facing a different error altogether with Angular 6.  I have added a `catch` to it as follows to see the error.

```
this.http.post('http://<server>:<port>/api/<urlpath>', {'somefield': 'somedata'}, { headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer})
.toPromise()
.then(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response))
.catch( error => { 
     console.error(error);
      });
```

And the error is

> {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
>   at JSON.parse ()

This error is a complete surprise for me. Not able to figure out where it went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 2**

Tried debugging. I see this in response:

> message: "Unexpected end of input"

I suspect the wrong usage of `HTTP`, but don't know what exactly that would be.